# Get the encoding of an string

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, html-agility-pack

I'm getting the html from other page with problems in codification. 
For example: 
I getting:

```
aparelho nas sa??das
```

the original text is:

```
aparelho nas saídas
```

How I get the encoding and convert to original string?

My code:

```
var GetResponse = API_GET("..."); //this returns html of an http request. 
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();  //the html-parsing 
doc.LoadHtml(GetResponse);
var body = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='para']"); 
... 
var para = body[i].InnerHtml; //Here's the problem,it returns the output like: sa??das
```

How I do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this - kind of does this. Checks for just utf-8. I think it's hard to check for encoding.

> **When in doubt, convert it into UTF-8 or else encoding = WTF!**

http://utf8checker.codeplex.com/releases/view/40052

Here's part of the source code. Look at the IsUtf8 Methods. Can be quite useful.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Unicode
{
    /// <summary>
    /// http://anubis.dkuug.dk/JTC1/SC2/WG2/docs/n1335
    /// 
    /// http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/ISO-10646-UTF-8.html
    /// 
    /// http://www.unicode.org/versions/corrigendum1.html
    /// 
    /// http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2279.txt
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public class Utf8Checker : IUtf8Checker
    {
        public bool Check(string fileName)
        {
            using (BufferedStream fstream = new BufferedStream(File.OpenRead(fileName)))
            {
                return this.IsUtf8(fstream);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Check if stream is utf8 encoded.
        /// Notice: stream is read completely in memory!
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="stream">Stream to read from.</param>
        /// <returns>True if the whole stream is utf8 encoded.</returns>
        public bool IsUtf8(Stream stream)
        {
            int count = 4 * 1024;
            byte[] buffer;
            int read;
            while (true)
            {
                buffer = new byte[count];
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, count);
                if (read < count)
                {
                    break;
                }
                buffer = null;
                count *= 2;
            }
            return IsUtf8(buffer, read);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="buffer"></param>
        /// <param name="length"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static bool IsUtf8(byte[] buffer, int length)
        {
            int position = 0;
            int bytes = 0;
            while (position < length)
            {
                if (!IsValid(buffer, position, length, ref bytes))
                {
                    return false;
                }
                position += bytes;
            }
            return true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="buffer"></param>
        /// <param name="position"></param>
        /// <param name="length"></param>
        /// <param name="bytes"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static bool IsValid(byte[] buffer, int position, int length, ref int bytes)
        {
            if (length > buffer.Length)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid length");
            }

            if (position > length - 1)
            {
                bytes = 0;
                return true;
            }

            byte ch = buffer[position];

            if (ch <= 0x7F)
            {
                bytes = 1;
                return true;
            }

            if (ch >= 0xc2 && ch <= 0xdf)
            {
                if (position >= length - 2)
                {
                    bytes = 0;
                    return false;
                }
                if (buffer[position + 1] < 0x80 || buffer[position + 1] > 0xbf)
                {
                    bytes = 0;
                    return false;
                }
                bytes = 2;
                return true;
            }

            if (ch == 0xe0)
            {
                if (position >= length - 3)
                {
                    bytes = 0;
                    return false;
                }

                if (buffer[position + 1] < 0xa0 || buffer[position + 1] > 0xbf ||
                    buffer[position + 2] < 0x80 || buffer[position + 2] > 0xbf)
                {
                    bytes = 0;
                    return false;
                }
                bytes = 3;
                return true;
            }


            if (ch >= 0xe1 && ch <= 0xef)
            {
                if (position >= length - 3)
                {
                    bytes = 0;
                    return false;
                }

                if (buffer[position + 1] < 0x80 || buffer[position + 1] > 0xbf ||
                    buffer[position + 2] < 0x80 || buffer[position + 2] > 0xbf)
                {
                    bytes = 0;
                    return false;
                }

                bytes = 3;
                return true;
            }

            if (ch == 0xf0)
            {
                if (position >= length - 4)
                {
                    bytes = 0;
                    return false;
                }

                if (buffer[position + 1] < 0x90 || buffer[position + 1] > 0xbf ||
                    buffer[position + 2] < 0x80 || buffer[position + 2] > 0xbf ||
                    buffer[position + 3] < 0x80 || buffer[position + 3] > 0xbf)
                {
                    bytes = 0;
                    return false;
                }

                bytes = 4;
                return true;
            }

            if (ch == 0xf4)
            {
                if (position >= length - 4)
                {
                    bytes = 0;
                    return false;
                }

                if (buffer[position + 1] < 0x80 || buffer[position + 1] > 0x8f ||
                    buffer[position + 2] < 0x80 || buffer[position + 2] > 0xbf ||
                    buffer[position + 3] < 0x80 || buffer[position + 3] > 0xbf)
                {
                    bytes = 0;
                    return false;
                }

                bytes = 4;
                return true;
            }

            if (ch >= 0xf1 && ch <= 0xf3)
            {
                if (position >= length - 4)
                {
                    bytes = 0;
                    return false;
                }

                if (buffer[position + 1] < 0x80 || buffer[position + 1] > 0xbf ||
                    buffer[position + 2] < 0x80 || buffer[position + 2] > 0xbf ||
                    buffer[position + 3] < 0x80 || buffer[position + 3] > 0xbf)
                {
                    bytes = 0;
                    return false;
                }

                bytes = 4;
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `HtmlDocument.Load(string path,Encoding encoding)` method. Read [this](http://www.fairnet.com/post/2010/08/28/Html-screen-scraping-with-HtmlAgilityPack-Library.aspx) post for more info.